# Fortran Program For Finding Biggest Number Among 3 Number

Tags: fortran

I'm learning Fortran. I had to write a program for finding highest/biggest number between 3 inputed number. It works fine except when I turn on interactive mode in 'JDoodle'. Again it works fine when I use Standard Text Input.

1. **When I Use Interactive Mode And Enter Decimal IE. 3.4 Type Number, it returns the number in 10th fold**
2. **Only Happens In JDoodle, Works Fine With Other Online Compiler**

Demos

1. [IDE One](https://ideone.com/6wk3aW)
2. [JDoodle](https://jdoodle.com/a/4Ugm)

My Code

```
! তিনটি সংখ্যা পড়ে তার থেকে বৃহত্তম সংখ্যা নির্ণয় করতে হবে

program compare
      print *, "Please Enter 3 Numbers:"
      read *, x,y,z
      if (x.lt.y .or. x.lt.z) then
        if (y.lt.z) then
        big = z
        else
        big = y
        end if
      else
      big = x
      end if
      print *, "The Biggest Number Is = ", big
end program compare
```

Comment: I get the expected answer when trying your code in JDoodle Interactive mode. Please specify exactly what we should try. Show us the exact result that you are getting.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава You probably Entered Integers. When I Enter Floating Numbers For Example 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 It'll Show highest number is 33.0000.... instead of 3.300000.... (Only Happens in interactive mode)

Comment: I really entered floating point numbers. I got   3.2999...  Yes, in interactive mode.